# Sequelize connection over ssh

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am not able to connect to a remote mysql server using sequelize but I am able to ssh into the machine and connect to mysql.

How do I make Sequelize connect to mysql server over ssh rather than directly in node?

Comment: i think sequelize doesn't support mysql connection over ssh.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You set up an SSH tunnel to your server, which listens on (for example) port 33060:

```
ssh -NL 33060:localhost:3306 yourserver
```

In another window/terminal, you can use the MySQL client (assuming that it's installed locally) to connect to the remote MySQL server over the SSH tunnel:

```
mysql --port 33060 --host 127.0.0.1
```

If that works, it's just a matter of changing the port number in Sequelize:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 33060
});
```

If it doesn't work, it might be that the remote MySQL server isn't configured to accept connections over TCP. If that's the case, you should configure your MySQL server to get it [to accept TCP connections](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,414677,414683#msg-414683).